# How do i use populate with a custom ObjectId of a type: String?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, firebase, mongoose

I have a firebase project that I use for authentication. I also save additional user info in the mongodb and assign the uid of the firebase user to the `_id` field of the user model. In order to do that, I have to set the type of ObjectId to a String, otherwise mongodb doesn't let me save the user as the firebase uid is a bit longer than ObjectId. It seems that the ObjectId is of type:String, I can no longer use populate on my queries.

Here are the models:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
});

const SurveySchema = new Schema({
  user_id: { type: String, ref: "users" },
  category: String,
});
```

I tried to set `user_id: { type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: "users" }`, but I just get an error(Cast to ObjectId failed) instead of undefined.

Here is the controller where I use populate:

```
const SurveyList = await Survey.find(
  {
    user_id: req.currentUser.uid,
    category: "example",
  },
  "_id user_id category createdAt updatedAt"
).populate("user_id");
```

I checked, the ids match, but I still get undefined. The populate used to work when I  had regular mongo ObjectIds, but after I started using firebase it no longer works.

The response I get is like this:

```
"SurveyList": [
    {
      "status": "1",
      "_id": "60abcd94e9cddb2ba44f24b4",
      "user_id": null,
      "category": "Health",
      "createdAt": "2021-05-24T16:00:20.688Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-05-24T16:00:20.688Z"
    }
  ]
```

Please note that the error began occurring only after I changed `_id` to `type:String`. It used to work fine when it was a default `mongoose.ObjectId`

Comment: why dont you try to populate by specifying path? is users is your model name? if so then try like this ```.populate({ path : 'user_id', model: 'users'})```

Comment: @xetryDcoder unfortunately that didn't work, still get `"user_id":null`

Comment: Are you able to get data without populating on SurveyList?

Comment: yes, I get all of the data, but the field I want to populate is simply null

Comment: can you update the question  with the response you are getting?

Comment: @xetryDcoder done

Comment: @NazarKlymenko your model name is incorrect, can you show how you are creating model, or try changing from `ref: "users"` to `ref: "User"`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot populate the field that you're using to store the reference to the user's id. That field is the one that will be used in order to populate the virtual field. If what you want to do is having a virtual field `SurveyList[i].user` that retrieves the user's data in each SurveyList entry, you need to create it:

```
SurveySchema.virtual("user", {
  ref: "users",
  localField: "user_id",
  foreignField: "_id",
  justOne: true,
});
```

Then you'll need to populate the virtual field:

```
const SurveyList = await Survey.find(
  {
    user_id: req.currentUser.uid,
    category: "example",
  },
  "_id user_id user category createdAt updatedAt"
).populate("user");
```

Comment: feel like I'm getting close, this approach populates the field with the id itself, like so: `"user_id":"kgnNFAbQZkOQu7QAz0qxybo3Yc22"`. Got an idea how can I populate with all of the values?

Comment: I don't think the field user_id needs to be populated in any way: it's the user._id, as you introduced it when you created the new SurveyList entry. Have you checked SurveyList[0].user? If .populate("user") worked as it should, each item in the SurveyList array would be expected to have a .user field containing all the user's original information.

Comment: no, the .user field is not there. Previously I used the `populate("user_id")` method, which returned me the user object inside the .user_id. It worked fine until I had to change the `_id` field of the user model to be of a `type: String`